# Remove item from listbox in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, win-universal-app

I have a listbox with items in my xaml page. I introduce those items programmatically (I don't know if this is important). I want to delete them as you do in an app like uwp mail.

I want that whenever you click over the left side, a checkbox appears and a button to send to trash those items. Is this a kind of components or on the contrary I have to code it?

Comment: _"I introduce those items programmatically"_ - Is your ListBox `ItemSource` binded to an `ObservableCollection` in your ViewModel?   If so, you can remove the item from the ObservableCollection

Comment: It is a listbox and all items are created as ItemTemplates->Datatemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the items in a list box, you can do it like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

If you want to activate a checkbox in XAML you can add it in the designer, set visible to false. Change it to true in your code behind when you want to activate it and use this to remove a selected item:

```
listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
```

You may need to iterate through all the items and check if they are selected.

Comment: Yes I know. But what I don't know, is to activate a checkbox in xaml to select which rows you want to remove. I see that feature in the mail app

Comment: So, there is no element in designer to create a "remove" part. I have to program it. Ok, I will check how to do that. Thank you!